# Installation issue in magento marketplace 'page doesn't contain HIT in cache header.'

Tags: magento2, module, installation, composer, marketplace

I have developed customer module in magento. When i am trying to submit in marketplace its keep giving the same error even after trying so many solutions.

```
Installation issue:
http://magento.dev/gear.html page doesn't contain HIT in cache header.
http://magento.dev/gear/bags.html page doesn't contain HIT in cache header.
http://magento.dev/gear/fitness-equipment.html page doesn't contain HIT in cache header.
http://magento.dev/gear/watches.html page doesn't contain HIT in cache header.
http://magento.dev/gear/bags/joust-duffle-bag.html page doesn't contain HIT in cache header.
http://magento.dev/collections/strive-shoulder-pack.html page doesn't contain HIT in cache header.
http://magento.dev/gear/bags/crown-summit-backpack.html page doesn't contain HIT in cache header.
http://magento.dev/collections/yoga-new/wayfarer-messenger-bag.html page doesn't contain HIT in cache header.
http://magento.dev/home page doesn't contain HIT in cache header.
http://magento.dev/enable-cookies page doesn't contain HIT in cache header.
http://magento.dev/privacy-policy-cookie-restriction-mode page doesn't contain HIT in cache header.
http://magento.dev/about-us page doesn't contain HIT in cache header.
http://magento.dev/customer-service page doesn't contain HIT in cache header.
http://magento.dev/gear/bags/joust-duffle-bag.html page doesn't contain HIT in cache header.   
Show less
```

if you guys have any solution then please update.

Thanks

Comment: Please check https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/212739/3720

Comment: did you get any solution?

Answer (score 2):

This is a message for Marketplace Support

"Hello,

Thank you for contacting Magento Marketplace Support.  The automated installation test provides the errors that need to be corrected in the technical report.  The technical report can be view/downloaded under the product submission.

The following link will guide with installation issues:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/system-requirements2.html

The following links will guide with Varnish cache issues:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/varnish/config-varnish.html

https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-DevBlog/Varnish-Cache-Validation-beginning-1-2-18/ba-p/81203

After looking at the report provided this appears to a Varnish Cache issue and should be corrected before resubmitting to the EQP process.

Note the Varnish Cache test was recently added to the automated installation test.

Please correct the issue(s) and resubmit to progress through the EQP process of Magento Marketplace.

Thank you,
Marketplace Support"

Comment: Thank you for your time and comment. I know this is marketplace issue but I want to know how I can resolve the issue as its creating bit of panic :-) if you have any solution for above issue then please update me thanks

Comment: I am with the same problem. for now I can not find a solution.

Comment: OK Miguel if you able to get the problem resolved please update me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The notable part of that is that they are automating the testing of the cache hit and miss submission. A fantastic thing, as the full page cache functioning is very critical to a Magento 2 sites speed. So it turns out that as stated in one of the supporting documents.  That if in ANY BLOCK included in the page has cacheable=”false” then that will disable the cache for the entire page.  WOW.  So though I get why this is the implications are pretty huge, and thankfully Magento is testing for this. It means that in any of the layout files anywhere that get included on your pages if you mistakenly include this then the entire page won’t cache.

For example

```
<block class="Xumulus\Locator\Block\Link" cacheable="false" name="store-locator-link" template="Store_Locator::link.phtml">
```

In our case, the block was a location service block so the developer was thinking it was best to not cache this.  Well, in this case, it would have invalidated the page cache for every page on the site.  It would have bypassed varnish and simply regenerated every time.  So its a very good thing it was caught!

But since most of us don’t have this nifty little validation tool that Magento has you can do the same test manually.  Simply do this in your local or dev environment.

1. Place store in Developer Mode
2. Inspect the page headers in your browsers debug network tab.
3. Look forX-Magento-Cache-Debug: MISS
4. Refresh the page, it should change to HIT

Rest assured this now has made it into our standard QA process of sites and extensions.  But for you developers out there, beware, as this one is a bit tricky and it’s not at all obvious that this will break the full page cache on any included page.

Complete info in https://xumulus.com/make-sure-magento-2-full-page-cache-will-working-order-site/

Comment: Unfortunately, i don't have any block in my module.

Comment: and default.xml?

Comment: module does not have any view and block related files.

Answer (score 0):

FYI if your not using layout / view and still get this problem see

[how to set no-cache HTTP headers in controller in magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/236019/how-to-set-no-cache-http-headers-in-controller-in-magento-2)

this is how you can set your controller/observer to use no cache and avoid this error