# how to set no-cache HTTP headers in controller in magento 2

Tags: magento2, session, full-page-cache, http-header

I have read in [Magento 2 Dev Docs for **Public content**](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/cache/page-caching/public-content.html)  we can set **no-cache HTTP headers** for Controllers that don’t use layouts(last line in page).

> Controllers that don’t use layouts should set no-cache HTTP headers.

I have a controller which use data from session object and when we enable **FPC** it doesn't work.

So I'm thinking to set **no-cache HTTP headers** for that controller may get data from ***the session object***.

Let me know if I'm wrong somewhere.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you look in

```
vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor
```

Line 85 onwards:

```
$response = $this->_responseFactory->create();
$response->setRedirect($redirectUrl, $redirectCode);
$response->setNoCacheHeaders();
return $response;
```

That may help. Good luck!