# Page doesn't contain HIT in cache header

Tags: magento2, cache, varnish, marketplace

I am publishing my magento extension but in the revision I was notified of the issue:

[image]
Does anyone have any useful help?

Comment: Did you solve your issue? Was my answer any help?

Comment: thanks for your help. I have already removed all tags cacheable = "false" from my extension but the problem persists. Any other idea? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you've added `cacheable="false"`  on some block located in product view page i.e. `catalog_product_view.xml` due to which cache is getting disabled for entire product view page as mentioned here -
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/cache/page-caching.html

> Cacheable and uncacheable are terms we use to indicate whether or not a page should be cached at all. (By default, all pages are
>   cacheable.) If any block in a layout is designated as uncacheable, the
>   entire page is uncacheable.

So, you must work on some workaround to disable cache for your own block if you had done `cacheable="false"` intentionally i.e hole punching in magento full page cache.

I good start will be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9120413/how-do-i-include-a-dynamic-block-in-the-product-page-with-full-page-caching-turn/9125519#9125519

Comment: thanks for your help.

I have already removed all tags cacheable = "false" from my extension but the problem persists. Any other idea?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

FYI if your not using layout / view and still get this problem see

[how to set no-cache HTTP headers in controller in magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/236019/how-to-set-no-cache-http-headers-in-controller-in-magento-2)

this is how you can set your controller/observer to use no cache and avoid this error