# Magento 2 : Expected HIT on the second page load after product price update while Marketplace submission

Tags: magento2, marketplace

I am trying to submit an extension to Magento marketplace but Magento team reported below issue in their test report:

> Expected HIT on the second page load. Expected HIT on the second page
>   load after product price update.
>
> {"command":"Varnish PageCache Test","output":{"Expected HIT on the
>   second page load.":["http://magento.local/simple-product-1.html
>   page doesn't contain HIT in cache
>   header.","http://magento.local/simple-product-2.html page doesn't
>   contain HIT in cache
>   header.","http://magento.local/simple-product-3.html page doesn't
>   contain HIT in cache header.","http://magento.local/category-1.html
>   page doesn't contain HIT in cache
>   header.","http://magento.local/category-2.html page doesn't contain
>   HIT in cache header.","http://magento.local/ page doesn't contain
>   HIT in cache header."],"Expected HIT on the second page load after
>   product price update.":["http://magento.local/simple-product-1.html
>   page doesn't contain HIT in cache
>   header.","http://magento.local/simple-product-3.html page doesn't
>   contain HIT in cache header."]}

I checked for similar issues, tried their solutions and confirmed that I am not using `cacheable="false"` in xml and `$this->_isScopePrivate = true` anywhere in my code/Blocks.

I am not sure what exactly to add to get the package be successfully validated at Magento Marketplace. Please help me if someone have any idea on it.

Comment: read from here - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/208540/installation-issue-in-magento-marketplace-page-doesnt-contain-hit-in-cache-hea?rq=1

Comment: I already checked that question and verified, I didn't set cacheable="false" anywhere in my xml or $this->_isScopePrivate = true in my code :)